# How do you create transparent bitmap with a specific color (not black)?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-bitmap, porter-duff

A transparent pixel consists of an alpha value of zero and arbitrary values of red, green and blue. So even if a pixel is transparent it still has a color.

I now want to create a bitmap which is fully transparent, but has a specific color (e.g. White). But with every method I tried I get a transparent bitmap with the color black (like in png files).

This is very important to me, because I render anti-aliased text on the bitmap through a canvas. And on the corners the semi-transparent pixels get darker. What I want to do is to fill the bitmap or canvas beforehand with the same color as the text, but transparent.

My code

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//bitmap manipultion here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//canvas manipulation here
canvas.drawText(gText, 0, bounds.height(), paint);
```

What I tried so far (`red`, `green` and `blue` are non-zero):

Canvas manipulation:

This one does the same as with the `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER`. I thought `SRC` overwrites the destination with source alpha and source color, or am I wrong?

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(0, red, green, blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

I also tried this one, but it generates a transparent black bitmap.

```
paint.setColor(Color.argb(0, red, green, blue));
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, paint);
```

Bitmap manipulation:

This doesn't change anything on a transparent (black) bitmap

```
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, red, green, blue));
```

I tried this one in the hope that the first line overwrites everything with my color and that the second one then makes it transparent. But it gives a transparent black bitmap.

```
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(255, red, green, blue));
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, red, green, blue));
```

This one also generates a transparent black bitmap

```
for(int x = 0; x<bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(0, red, green, blue));
    }
}
```

What can I do to generate a non-black and transparent bitmap?  Or is it even possible (because of automatic compression)?

Comment: It has been some time since you have asked this question, can you perhaps remember what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing red green and blue in your last attempt all to 255, which should add up to white (red + green + blue == white, 255 being the max.

```
for(int x = 0; x<bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I actually tried. I still get a transparent but black bitmap.
"White" was just an example. I wrote red, green and blue to emphasize that I want it to work with every color.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your activity in the Manifest attr:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

At least you'll get some answer if hardware acceleration deletes transparent bitmaps